# javaScript: how do i check if argument matches the last string in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I check if the argument passed into nameSearch matches the last item in the names array?

```js
function nameSearch(name) {
  var names = ["lopi", "aja", "lombo", "dakes", "polq", "kinto", "lufe"];
  var i = 0;

  while (i < names.length) {
    if (names[i] !== name) {
      console.log("The current name is " + names[i]);

      if (name === names.indexOf(names.length - 1)) { //option one,did not work
        if (name === names.indexOf("lufe")) { //option two hard coded,still did not work
          console.log("This is the last name in the directory");
        }

      } else {
        console.log("We found " + names[i] + " he is number " + i);
        break;

      }

      i++;
    }

  }
  nameSearch("lufe");
```

Comment: compare it to `array[array.length - 1]` or that `indexOf` returns `array.length - 1` - though, as asked, the first method I mentioned is the most efficient - note, indexOf returns a number

Comment: Thank you, i just need to move it outside the loop

Comment: sure ... that's it